# React useAsync hook returning undefined when returning dict

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const { value: instanceData, loading: isLoading } = useAsync(async () => {
    instances = [];
    resource_name = "hello"
    return {instances, resource_name}l
  }, []);
  const instances = instanceData.instances; // undefined!
  const resource_name = instanceData.resource_name; // undefined!
```

I don't understand why the variables I'm getting returned are undefined ?

Comment: Which library are you using? AFAIK, `useAsync` is not part of React core.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which library are you using and why don't you use normal `useEffect` for that but I assume `useAsync` is async so it has to wait for some data to get and that is why `instanceData.instances` is `undefined` because that data didn't come yet. The fastest fix would be just adding question mark to your const values:

```
  const instances = instanceData?.instances; 
  const resource_name = instanceData?.resource_name;
```

But later on in the `jsx` you have to also check if they are not undefined.

This is my solution but because I don't know what exactly happens by useAsync I am not sure if that would work.